# Javascript Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, function, class, oop

as you can see in the title I have a problem multiple people have had on this platform, but nothing works for me. I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new UseArray (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:346:20)
    at new Elements (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:121:26)
    at new Structure (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:63:29)
    at new CreateLink (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:310:30)
    at new Navigation (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:294:25)
    at new Elements (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:123:24)
    at new Structure (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:63:29)
    at new CreateLink (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:310:30)
    at new Navigation (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:294:25)
    at new Elements (quiz.html?_ijt=b3fubmjhnt75jg0ptc21kkq5g3&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE:123:24)
```

I have no idea how to fix it because I tried everything I could find the last couple of hours.
The main problem seems to be this function:

```
    class DropdownFunctions {

        DropDownClose(e) {
            const tgt = e.target;
            if (tgt.matches('.dropBtn')) {
                this.DropDownCloseFunction();
            }
        }

        DropDownCloseFunction() {
            let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDiv");
            for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                } else {
                    openDropdown.classList.add('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have a lot of functions like this:

```
    class CreateLink {
        constructor() {
            this.tmp = []
            this.array = new UseArray();
            this.structure = new Structure(this.array.Quiz);
        }

        getLink() {
            let url = this.structure.url;
            for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
                // Check if question is from the same quiz part and adds a , between chosen answers and add the right prefix at the beginning
                if (url[i].length > 0) {
                    this.tmp.push("" + this.array.Quiz[i].prefix + url[i].join(","))
                }
            }
            // If answers are from different quiz parts add a & between answers
            return "" + this.tmp.join("&");
        }

    }
```

Anybody know a way to fix it?
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thijsl0705/1s98gumk/4/

Comment: `Structure` calls `CreateLink` calls `Navigation` calls `Elements` calls `Structure` calls `CreateLink` calls `Navigation` calls `Elements` calls `Structure` calls  ...

Comment: @Teemu That's true but isn't there another way to connect them? or do I have to put them all in the same class?